# Applescript get name of file without extension

Tags: applescript

I want to get the name without extension of one file in folder which extention is mp4 or mov and put it in a variable. In this folder therie is mulitple file but only one is in mp4 or mov.

For now, here is what i have:

```
set _ext to {"mp4", "mov"}
set _folder to "path_folder"

tell application "Finder"
   set _name to name of every file of _folder whose name extension is in "_ext"
end tell
```

anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

There are some other issues in the script, try this one. It uses more descriptive variable names, the variable `baseName` contains the result, the file name without extension.

```
set allowedExtensions to {"mp4", "mov"}
set targetFolder to "path_folder"

tell application "Finder"
    try
        set {name:fileName, name extension:fileExtension} to first file of folder targetFolder whose name extension is in allowedExtensions
        set baseName to text 1 thru ((get offset of "." & fileExtension in fileName) - 1) of fileName
    on error
        display dialog "File not found" buttons {"Cancel"} default button 1
    end try
end tell
```

Comment: hi, i try this but it always return "File not found" even if there is file with right extension in the folder

Comment: `targetFolder` must contain the full HFS path (colon separated) to the folder or the folder must be a subfolder of the desktop folder.

Comment: here how it looks :set targetFolder to "/Volumes/TRAVAIL/AUDIO/EN_COURS/CONVERSION.BOUNCE/BOUNCE/" and files are in the folder BOUNCE

Comment: I wrote  ***colon separated***: `"TRAVAIL:AUDIO:EN_COURS:CONVERSION.BOUNCE:BOUNCE:"` (no Volumes prefix !)